# How can I send Authlib requests through a proxy?

Tags: authlib, flask-oauthlib

With requests I can make a request through a proxy:

```
import requests
proxies = {
    "http": "http://proxy.yourorg.com:80",
    "https": "http://proxy.yourorg.com:80"
}
url = 'http://myorg.com/example'
response = requests.post(url, proxies=proxies)
```

Does Authlib provide a mechanism to use proxies for requests?

```
token = oauth.discord.authorize_access_token()
resp = oauth.discord.get('/users/@me')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Authlib is using `requests`, while `requests` support proxy through HTTP_PROXY environment variables, you can set:

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.yourorg.com:80"
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://proxy.yourorg.com:80"
```

While Authlib also support passing `proxies` into the parameters, try:

```
token = oauth.discord.authorize_access_token(proxies=proxies)
```